why does typescript narrow a discriminated union object to any instead of never?
I have a tagged/discriminated union in typescript that defines several input types.
Now, when I write a helper function with a exhaustive switch based on the type field (the discriminator) typescript is incorrectly narrowing the final type to any (instead of the expected never).
Exhaustive means that I handle all the cases and in the default branch I put an assertion of something that should never be reached. Is in that last default part where typescript is  incorrectly inferring the input to be any (when it should be never)
Here is the complete code for reference:
type inputType = {
    type: "select";
    source: "notes";
    folder: string;
} | {
    type: "tag";
    exclude?: string | undefined;
} | {
    type: "slider";
    min: number;
    max: number;
} | {
    type: "note";
    folder: string;
} | {
    type: "folder";
} | {
    type: "dataview";
    query: string;
} | {
    type: "number" | "text" | "date" | "time" | "datetime" | "textarea" | "toggle" | "email" | "tel";
} | {
    type: "select";
    source: "fixed";
    options: {
        value: string;
        label: string;
    }[];
} | {
    type: "multiselect";
    source: "notes";
    folder: string;
} | {
    type: "multiselect";
    source: "fixed";
    multi_select_options: string[];
    allowUnknownValues: boolean;
} | {
    type: "multiselect";
    source: "dataview";
    query: string;
    allowUnknownValues: boolean;
} | {
    type: "document_block";
    body: string;
}

function absurd<T>(_:never):T{
throw new Error('Absurd!')

}

export function requiresListOfStrings(input: inputType): boolean {
    switch (input.type) {
        case "multiselect":
        case "tag":
            return true;
        case "select":
        case "dataview":
        case "note":
        case "folder":
        case "slider":
        case "document_block":
        case "number":
        case "text":
        case "date":
        case "time":
        case "datetime":
        case "textarea":
        case "toggle":
        case "email":
        case "tel":
            return false;
        default:
            return absurd(input.type); // Here is the error
    }
}

And this is the error typescript is reporting:
Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'.

I know I can easily workaround this by extracting the type property into a variable like this:
export function requiresListOfStrings(input: inputType): boolean {
    const type = input.type;
    switch (type) {
        case "multiselect":
        case "tag":
            return true;
        case "select":
        // yada yada...
        case "tel":
            return false;
        default:
            return absurd(type);
    }
}

But I want to understand the why of the error.
I tested this in 5.4 and 5.5 and fails in both.
here is a playground link in case it helps

Inside the default branch, input gets the type never so accessing .type on it is an error. (The error message is confusing though.)
For example, doing:
console.log(input.type)

throws a better error: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339) .
You should just pass input to absurd:
default:
    return absurd(input);

